# Running SQL based on a query stored within a field?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to populate a database with certain values, based on a query stored within another table.

**Table1:**

```
ID      SQL                                         Title
1       select ID from userTable where ID = 1       Query 1
2       select ID from userTable where ID > 7       Query 2
```

I basically need to grab the 'SQL' field, and populate another table with information from the above, once the script has run it'll look something like:

```
ID      userID      Title
1       1           Query 1
2       8           Query 2
2       9           Query 2
2       10          Query 2
```

And so on.

I hope that makes sense, I have absolutely no clue if it's possible - I've tried creating it as a procedure but I can't find anyway whatsoever to run the 'SQL' code from table 1 in the procedure.

Alternatively I will do it in PHP, though it'd be preferable to get this into SQL as it's easier to automate.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an odd thing to be doing (I would query why) but this code should do it:

```
declare
  rc sys_refcursor;
  l_id table1.id%type;
begin
  for r_sql in (select id, sql, title from table1) loop
    open rc for r_sql.sql;
    loop
      fetch rc into l_id;
      exit when rc%notfound;
      insert into table2 (id, userid, title) values (r_sql.id, l_id, r_sql.title);
    end loop;
    close rc;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Ah, you're a star - thank you so much, will try to implement this now (as for why, we're trying to populate a reminders/notification section just for certain people)